# Loading TF1 universal sentence encoder into TF2 - hub

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to load a TF1 model, using hub and following [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/docs/migration_tf2.md) guide.

This model has a sentencepiece model which comes with it:

```
spm_path = m.signatures['spm_path']
<tensorflow.python.eager.wrap_function.WrappedFunction at 0x1341129e8>
```

If I execute this function:

```
spm_path()
{'default': <tf.Tensor: id=5905, shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'SAVEDMODEL-ASSET'>}
```

However if I use the output of `b'SAVEDMODEL-ASSET'` to load my `sentencepiece` model - I get the following error:

```
sp.Load(b'SAVEDMODEL-ASSET')
OSError: Not found: "SAVEDMODEL-ASSET": No such file or directory Error #2
```

The issue is that I am not sure where this asset is located - where does hub store dowloaded modules?

I can find the following: `os.environ['TFHUB_CACHE_DIR'] = '/tmp/tfhub'` but this is not enough for me to locate the actual file on my machine and pass in the correct file.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit clunky but here's one way to do it:

```
uselite = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-lite/2")

sp = sentencepiece.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp.load(uselite.asset_paths[0].asset_path.numpy())
```

The `asset_paths` contains only one item and it's the path to the spm model.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, trying to load the assets needed for the tokenization for the ALBERT model. I found that there is an asset list in m.asset_paths. There are the Asset objects, and you can access the path with the .asset_path property. The problem is that you need to check the paths of the assets, to find the one that you need. Maybe there is a better way, but I don't know it.

Comment: Yeah I fixed this by manually adding the path from the downloaded files.